# How do you use "v-nails" on picture frames?

Tags: nailing, nails, framing

I have tried using v-nails when making picture frames, but didn't have much luck. I tried using a hammer, a hammer+punch, and finger pushing.

There must be a trick to this.

[image]

What are the tricks to getting v-nails to work on picture frames like the pros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rockler has a [V-Nail Installation Tool](http://www.rockler.com/ezy-framer-v-nail-installation-tool) that should be right up your alley:

[image: nailer #1]

[image: nailer #2]

I'm sure there are other stores where you can get these, but this is the first one I found.

Comment: @NipFu, [Additional site](http://grignonsart.com/pictureframingsupplies/v-nails.html) showing some steps for doing so (not in the Answer because the link could break at some point)

Comment: Links are fine in answers. They should not be the focus though. If you think it is useful put it in the answer so that people will see it. Not everyone reads comments.

Comment: On the other hand, @Matt, that link is very self-serving advertising, even in the "how to" section. (Self serving for the site linked to, not grfrazee. Unless, of course, he owns that site. :)

Comment: @FreeMan, I do not :-)

Comment: @FreeMan Under those circumstances then yes you could be right. I was merely referring to grafazee's reasoning about links. Links are fine in general but those might not serve users well and are maybe better as comments. Perhaps there is something better out there.

Comment: @grfrazee - if you owned that site, yet posted a link to Rockler first, I'd wonder... ;)

Comment: All links are broken now.